# 2 dimensional array php array_push warning

Tags: php

now i want to push some values with foreach into it

```
array_push($nachbar[$key],$key);
```

In the array is already a array with some values and these values will get now own values.

```
Array
(
    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => e
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => g
        )

)
```

In the end it looks so , but my problem is the warning " array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array", I know warning are not sooo bad, but I dont want this.
Can anyone help me? Sry if it is a little bit unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$nachbar[$key]` need to be an array to push some element inside

try this:

```
$nachbar[$key] = array();
array_push($nachbar[$key],$key);
```

Comment: `if( !is_array($nachbar[$key]) ) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple");
print_r($stack);
```

Answer (score 0):

btw it's a best practice to not use array_push if only pushing 1 element at a time...

You could just as easily use

```
$nachbar[$key][] = $key;
```